# ElasticSearch CloudFormation - Property VpcId cannot be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

I created the following CloudFormation Template to kick up an ElasticSearch Domain. I want to use EXISTING VPC and Subnets, however, when I went through and modified this to do that, I get an error when standing up the stack that states:

"Property VpcId cannot be empty."

Yet, in the template parameters, you select the VpcId...

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  **NOTE** In order to create Elastisearch Domain in AWS using CloudFormation
  verify you have the following Service Role created in IAM!!
  -- AWSServiceRoleForAmazonElasticsearchService --
  If you do not have this Role, create it using the following CLi Command -- 
  aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name es.amazonaws.com

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: "Configure Cluster"
        Parameters:
          - DomainName
          - ElasticsearchVersion
          - ZoneAwareness
      -
        Label:
          default: "Data Instances"
        Parameters:
          - InstanceType
          - DataInstanceCount
      -
        Label:
          default: "Dedicated Master Instances"
        Parameters:
          - DedicatedMaster
          - MasterInstanceType
          - MasterInstanceCount
      -
        Label:
          default: "Storage Config"
        Parameters:
          - StorageSize
      -
        Label:
          default: "Network Config"
        Parameters:
          - VpcId
          - SubNet1
          - SubNet2
          - AvailabilityZone
          - AvailabilityZone2
          - SecurityGroup
          - GroupDescription
      -
        Label:
          default: "IAM User Restriction Policy"
        Parameters:
          - IamUserArn
    ParameterLabels:
      DomainName:
        default: "Name of the ElasticSearch Domain (lowecase, no spaces) - If you don't specify a name, AWS CloudFormation generates a unique physical ID and uses that ID for the domain name"
      ElasticsearchVersion:
        default: "Select the ElasticSearch version desired"
      InstanceType:
        default: "Instance Size of Data Instances"
      DataInstanceCount:
        default: "Number of Data Instances Required"
      DedicatedMaster:
        default: "Select if a Dedicated Master Instance is required"
      MasterInstanceType:
        default: "Instance Size of Master Instances"
      MasterInstanceCount:
        default: "How many Dedicated Master Instances are needed? (0, 3 or 5)"
      StorageSize:
        default: "Storage Size in GB"
      VpcId:
        default: "Select the VPC to deploy into (must already exist)"
      SubNet1:
        default: "Select the First Subnet"
      SubNet2:
        default: "Select the Second Subnet"
      GroupDescription:
        default: "New Security Group Description"
      SecurityGroup:
        default: "Name of the New Security Group"
      IamUserArn:
        default: "Enter the ARN for the IAM User to give initial access to the stack"
      ZoneAwareness:
        default: "Enable Zone Awareness (Availability Zone Replication) (recommended)"

Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: "elasticsearchstack-cf"
    MaxLength: '128' 
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  ElasticsearchVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: 7.1
    AllowedValues: [7.1, 6.8, 6.7, 6.6, 6.5] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium.elasticsearch
    AllowedValues: [t2.small.elasticsearch, t2.medium.elasticsearch,
      c4.large.elasticsearch, c4.xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      c5.large.elasticsearch, c5.xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.9xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.18xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m3.medium.elasticsearch, m3.large.elasticsearch, m3.xlarge.elasticsearch, m3.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m4.large.elasticsearch, m4.xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.10xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m5.large.elasticsearch, m5.xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r3.large.elasticsearch, r3.xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r4.large.elasticsearch, r4.xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.16xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r5.large.elasticsearch, r5.xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i2.xlarge.elasticsearch, i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i3.large.elasticsearch, i3.xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.8xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.16xlarge.elasticsearch]
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid EC2 Elasticsearch instance type."
  DataInstanceCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2
    AllowedValues: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  MasterInstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium.elasticsearch
    AllowedValues: [t2.small.elasticsearch, t2.medium.elasticsearch,
      c4.large.elasticsearch, c4.xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      c5.large.elasticsearch, c5.xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.9xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.18xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m3.medium.elasticsearch, m3.large.elasticsearch, m3.xlarge.elasticsearch, m3.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m4.large.elasticsearch, m4.xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.10xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m5.large.elasticsearch, m5.xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r3.large.elasticsearch, r3.xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r4.large.elasticsearch, r4.xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.16xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r5.large.elasticsearch, r5.xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i2.xlarge.elasticsearch, i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i3.large.elasticsearch, i3.xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.8xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.16xlarge.elasticsearch]
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid EC2 Elasticsearch instance type."
  MasterInstanceCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 0
    AllowedValues: [0, 3, 5] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the VPC ID of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
  SubNet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the Subnet ID of an existing Subnet."
  SubNet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the Subnet ID of an existing Subnet."    
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: String
    Default: "elasticsearchstack-nsg"
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  DedicatedMaster:
    Description: True or False
    Type: String
    Default: False
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
  StorageSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 20
    MinValue: 10 # Remove this line for free-form number entry (suggested to keep this line)
    MaxValue: 1000 # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  GroupDescription: # Security Group Description
    Type: String
    Default: "ElasticSearch Stack from CloudFormation"
    MaxLength: '128'
    ConstraintDescription: "Upper/Lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  IamUserArn:
    Type: String
    Default: "arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumber>:user/<username>"
  ZoneAwareness:
    Description: True or False
    Type: String
    Default: True
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
Conditions: # Checks to see if Dedicated Master is True
  DedicatedMasterYes: !Equals [ !Ref DedicatedMaster, True]

Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      ElasticsearchVersion: !Ref ElasticsearchVersion
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig: 
        DedicatedMasterEnabled: !Ref DedicatedMaster
        InstanceCount: !Ref DataInstanceCount
        ZoneAwarenessEnabled: !Ref ZoneAwareness
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        DedicatedMasterType: # If Dedicated Master is True, then use !Ref, if not, use NoValue (NULL)
          !If [DedicatedMasterYes, !Ref MasterInstanceType, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
        DedicatedMasterCount: 
          !If [DedicatedMasterYes, !Ref MasterInstanceCount, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: True
        Iops: 0
        VolumeSize: !Ref StorageSize
        VolumeType: "gp2"
      SnapshotOptions:
        AutomatedSnapshotStartHour: "0"
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Deny
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref IamUserArn
            Action: 'es:*'
            Resource: "*"
      AdvancedOptions: # BOTH of these settingsd are REQUIRED (regardless of what the documentation states) - Bug filed: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=768527
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
        indices.fielddata.cache.size: !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      VPCOptions:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref subnet1
          - !Ref subnet2
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref mySecurityGroup
  subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  mySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupName: !Ref SecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: !Ref GroupDescription
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: '443'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '443'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

Outputs:
  DomainArn:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainArn
  DomainEndpoint:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainEndpoint
  SecurityGroupId:
    Value: !Ref mySecurityGroup
  SubnetId:
    Value: !Ref subnet1
  SubnetId2:
    Value: !Ref subnet2
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple, but my brain is fried. Thanks all!

Comment: try to remove `VpcId: !Ref VpcId` from `VPCOptions`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-vpcoptions.html

Comment: Thanks for the assist! However, that made no difference. I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: This is not related to elasticsearch, looks like you did not assign any value to vpcid

Comment: I think I am working it out. I managed to get past that error, but ran into another, so I will work through these and see if I can fix this. Will post the solution if anyone is interested.

@AmitBaranes - Not sure what you mean, this is a template that I am using to create an ElasticSearch Domain, but that's neither here nor there really. Thanks for the input though. (and if you look at the tags, I tagged AWS-ElasticSearch, not just plain ElasticSearch, because I agree that this is not related directly to ElasticSearch on it's own).

Comment: I got past the initial error with the following:
```
  subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
```
However, now, I am getting pretty much the same error except it's complaining about CIDR Block being empty, so need to find a way to pull this from an existing subnet.

Comment: No, you don't need the cidr from an existing subnet. So have a look at your template, you are actually creating two subnets where you have Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet. If you want to use existing subnets then you need to remove the resources called subnet1 and subnet2. Then in your parameters section you need to pass in the subnet ID of your existing subnets.

Comment: @WarrenG Thanks for that, it helps, but now I am getting an error: "You must specify two subnets. (Service: AWSElasticsearch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 1c7560c3-f67d-11e9-b564-f917b806ece1)". So, under VPCOptions, I add (Sorry for formatting, comments suck for this):

      SubnetIds:
          - !Ref subnet1
          - !Ref subnet2

but now the template is "invalid" with:

Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [subnet1, subnet2] in the Resources block of the template

Comment: Under you VPCOptions section of your ElasticsearchDomain resource, change Value: !Ref subnet1 to Value: !Ref SubNet1, and do similar with subnet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WarrenG - Thanks for that, I just managed to get that figured out too...

Here is the working, fixed template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  **NOTE** In order to create Elastisearch Domain in AWS using CloudFormation
  verify you have the following Service Role created in IAM!!
  -- AWSServiceRoleForAmazonElasticsearchService --
  If you do not have this Role, create it using the following CLi Command -- 
  aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name es.amazonaws.com

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: "Configure Cluster"
        Parameters:
          - DomainName
          - ElasticsearchVersion
          - ZoneAwareness
          - SnapShotHour
      -
        Label:
          default: "Data Instances"
        Parameters:
          - InstanceType
          - DataInstanceCount
      -
        Label:
          default: "Dedicated Master Instances"
        Parameters:
          - DedicatedMaster
          - MasterInstanceType
          - MasterInstanceCount
      -
        Label:
          default: "Storage Config"
        Parameters:
          - StorageSize
      -
        Label:
          default: "Network Config"
        Parameters:
          - VpcId
          - SubNet1
          - SubNet2
          - SecurityGroup
          - GroupDescription
      -
        Label:
          default: "IAM User Restriction Policy"
        Parameters:
          - IamUserArn
    ParameterLabels:
      DomainName:
        default: "Name of the ElasticSearch Domain (lowecase, no spaces) - If you don't specify a name, AWS CloudFormation generates a unique physical ID and uses that ID for the domain name"
      ElasticsearchVersion:
        default: "Select the ElasticSearch version desired"
      InstanceType:
        default: "Instance Size of Data Instances"
      DataInstanceCount:
        default: "Number of Data Instances Required"
      DedicatedMaster:
        default: "Select if a Dedicated Master Instance is required"
      MasterInstanceType:
        default: "Instance Size of Master Instances"
      MasterInstanceCount:
        default: "How many Dedicated Master Instances are needed? (0, 3 or 5)"
      StorageSize:
        default: "Storage Size in GB"
      VpcId:
        default: "Select the VPC to deploy into (must already exist)"
      SubNet1:
        default: "Select the First Subnet"
      SubNet2:
        default: "Select the Second Subnet"
      GroupDescription:
        default: "New Security Group Description"
      SecurityGroup:
        default: "Name of the New Security Group"
      IamUserArn:
        default: "Enter the ARN for the IAM User to give initial access to the stack"
      ZoneAwareness:
        default: "Enable Zone Awareness (Availability Zone Replication) (recommended)"
      SnapShotHour:
        default: "Set the hour to run the Automated Snapshot (0-23) (Default: UTC Timezone)"

Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: "elasticsearchstack-cf"
    MaxLength: '128' 
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  SnapShotHour:
    Type: Number
    Default: 0
    MinValue: 0
    MaxValue: 23
  ElasticsearchVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: 7.1
    AllowedValues: [7.1, 6.8, 6.7, 6.6, 6.5] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium.elasticsearch
    AllowedValues: [t2.small.elasticsearch, t2.medium.elasticsearch,
      c4.large.elasticsearch, c4.xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      c5.large.elasticsearch, c5.xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.9xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.18xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m3.medium.elasticsearch, m3.large.elasticsearch, m3.xlarge.elasticsearch, m3.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m4.large.elasticsearch, m4.xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.10xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m5.large.elasticsearch, m5.xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r3.large.elasticsearch, r3.xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r4.large.elasticsearch, r4.xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.16xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r5.large.elasticsearch, r5.xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i2.xlarge.elasticsearch, i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i3.large.elasticsearch, i3.xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.8xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.16xlarge.elasticsearch]
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid EC2 Elasticsearch instance type."
  DataInstanceCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2
    AllowedValues: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  MasterInstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium.elasticsearch
    AllowedValues: [t2.small.elasticsearch, t2.medium.elasticsearch,
      c4.large.elasticsearch, c4.xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c4.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      c5.large.elasticsearch, c5.xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.9xlarge.elasticsearch, c5.18xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m3.medium.elasticsearch, m3.large.elasticsearch, m3.xlarge.elasticsearch, m3.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m4.large.elasticsearch, m4.xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m4.10xlarge.elasticsearch,
      m5.large.elasticsearch, m5.xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, m5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r3.large.elasticsearch, r3.xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r3.8xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r4.large.elasticsearch, r4.xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r4.16xlarge.elasticsearch,
      r5.large.elasticsearch, r5.xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.2xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.4xlarge.elasticsearch, r5.12xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i2.xlarge.elasticsearch, i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch,
      i3.large.elasticsearch, i3.xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.2xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.4xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.8xlarge.elasticsearch, i3.16xlarge.elasticsearch]
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid EC2 Elasticsearch instance type."
  MasterInstanceCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 0
    AllowedValues: [0, 3, 5] # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the VPC ID of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
  SubNet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the Subnet ID of an existing Subnet."
  SubNet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the Subnet ID of an existing Subnet."    
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: String
    Default: "elasticsearchstack-nsg"
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  DedicatedMaster:
    Description: True or False
    Type: String
    Default: False
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
  StorageSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 20
    MinValue: 10 # Remove this line for free-form number entry (suggested to keep this line)
    MaxValue: 1000 # Remove this line for free-form number entry
  GroupDescription: # Security Group Description
    Type: String
    Default: "ElasticSearch Stack from CloudFormation"
    MaxLength: '128'
    ConstraintDescription: "Upper/Lowercase, numbers/letters and/or a dash"
  IamUserArn:
    Type: String
    Default: "arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumber>:user/<username>"
  ZoneAwareness:
    Description: True or False
    Type: String
    Default: True
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False
Conditions: # Checks to see if Dedicated Master is True
  DedicatedMasterYes: !Equals [ !Ref DedicatedMaster, True]

Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      ElasticsearchVersion: !Ref ElasticsearchVersion
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig: 
        DedicatedMasterEnabled: !Ref DedicatedMaster
        InstanceCount: !Ref DataInstanceCount
        ZoneAwarenessEnabled: !Ref ZoneAwareness
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        DedicatedMasterType: # If Dedicated Master is True, then use !Ref, if not, use NoValue (NULL)
          !If [DedicatedMasterYes, !Ref MasterInstanceType, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
        DedicatedMasterCount: 
          !If [DedicatedMasterYes, !Ref MasterInstanceCount, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: True
        Iops: 0
        VolumeSize: !Ref StorageSize
        VolumeType: "gp2"
      SnapshotOptions:
        AutomatedSnapshotStartHour: !Ref SnapShotHour
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Deny
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref IamUserArn
            Action: 'es:*'
            Resource: "*"
      AdvancedOptions: # BOTH of these settingsd are REQUIRED (regardless of what the documentation states) - Bug filed: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=768527
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
        indices.fielddata.cache.size: !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      VPCOptions:
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref SubNet1
          - !Ref SubNet2
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref mySecurityGroup
  mySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupName: !Ref SecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: !Ref GroupDescription
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: '443'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '443'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

Outputs:
  DomainArn:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainArn
  DomainEndpoint:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainEndpoint
  SecurityGroupId:
    Value: !Ref mySecurityGroup
```